# Первоклассник и первоклашка

Tags: выбор-слов

В чём различие между этими словами? Может, есть какие-то стилистические особенности в употреблении? В разговорной речи оба варианта встречаются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно толковому словарю под редакцией Кузнецова это слово имеет шутливый оттенок. Однако в предыдущих словарях (напр.: толковый словарь Ожегова, Шведовой) это слово давалось с помет. "Прост."

Comment: Сам я всегда говорю «первоклассник» и не припоминаю, чтобы использовал второй вариант.

Comment: Я тоже говорю первоклассник, не потому, что первый вариант отмечается в словарях как шутл. или прост., а просто в моем лексиконе это слово отсутствует.

Answer (score -1):

Первоклашка и первоклассник — это просторечия. Ученик начальных классов :)

Comment: Что ученик начальных классов?

Comment: подпись это....

Comment: Хехе)))))))))))